# Can I turn off the Tutorial in Fallout Shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've poked around in the menu a bit, but I don't see a way to turn off the tutorial for Fallout Shelter. Having lost a vault to a bugged bug (an unkillable radroach) I'd prefer to not have to go through the whole tutorial again.

Comment: I'm curious too, since I think it makes you put the first few rooms in certain locations, and if I restart I'd prefer a different configuration.

Comment: It doesn't actually force you to place the rooms where the arrow is pointing, it will handle it if you place the rooms in a way where they can be expanded later on. You still have to buy in that order though.

Comment: The tutorial does force you to build a room immediately to the right of your living area. I'd prefer to expand my living area to 3 and then build there...

Comment: Part of the challenge is saving up caps and rebuilding it how you want, after the fact... You can wipe out any room so long as every other room connects to the vault door. My preferred configuration is to have an elevator on either side of each of my rooms, and that can't happen so long as there's only one elevator shaft between the vault door and the living quarters. And actually, it makes more sense to wipe the first floor living quarters out anyway, since you want armed dwellers on the first floor and how often do you ever leave the living quarters fully populated!

Comment: You can turn off the tips though, go to the pip boy menu tap on the gear icon and there should be a turn off tips option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Bethesda's official [Fallout Shelter Updates thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1530866-fallout-shelter-updates/), the ability to skip the tutorial was added in version 1.2:

> Are you an experienced Overseer who has already undergone Vault operational training? Now you can skip the tutorial!

When you start a new vault, there is an intro screen congratulating you on being selected as the new overseer. In the upper-right corner of this screen you will find the option to 'skip'. This skips the tutorial.

Here is the screen I'm referring to, pre-patch:

[image]

The game will start with the vault entrance, three levels of elevator, and a line of dwellers outside the vault.

Comment: This does not exist. No button there, tried to find it several times. At least not in the Android version.

Comment: @Chase It was there in 2016. I haven't played this game in years.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to stop or skip the tutorial. You must play it through, however you do not need to put the rooms in the spots the arrows are pointing, and can put them anywhere you would normally be able to put them.

Comment: The arrows are only pointing at spots where you would normally be able to put rooms. What are you trying to say?

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, the original tutorial told you exactly where to place the first rooms, but now you have the same options as a normal room (ie the game outlines all acceptable room placement options).